# Windows API Functions in FORTRAN - What series of API's is needed to Simulate a Window MAXimise button action?

Tags: winapi, fortran

first off, I'm very new to using API's so please bear with me I'm on a steep learning curve !

I'm creating an application using Silverfrost Fortran FTN95.

I've been trying to initiate the opening of an initial  Window within the program which uses the whole screen 
useable area (the so-called WORKAREA in API parlance) but am having a problem.
Having used GET_WINDOW_LOCATION@ API function within my Fortran code to obtain the dimensions and origin of the max possible area for 
the window (without taskbar), I've then defined the 'origin' of the window to be at -n,-n where the border is n pixels thick and I've 
increased the window dimensions by (2xn) in each direction so that the other 2 borders will be off-screen at top or under the taskbar at the bottom edge).

Anyway, I'm having difficulty obtaining exactly the same as produced via clicking the 'MAXimise button' on a window.

While the window produced itself seems to occupy the whole area available, when it appears the CAption appears right on the upper edge of the 
CAption ba(i.e. not centre justified vertically).
Also, the MINimise, MAXimise and CLOSE buttons in top rh corner of window do not fill the whole depth of the CAption bar (they're about half the depth and indeed appear to be cut-off).

If I subsequently click the window 'MAXimise button' after initial window creation then the CAption and buttons re-align themselves correctly.

This is all illustrated in this image here:-

http://s1164.photobucket.com/user/john_pbucket/media/SilverfrostForumsImageFiles/MAXWIN-Summary_zpscajfx3vx.png.html

Note - I first created the full window with borders within the available screen area (this is the first example shown) where the window Border (8pix wide) is visible
       The subsequent attempt to create the window as per  the MAXimise button places the window at origin (-8,-8) and I increase the window dimensions by 16 (2xborder width) in each direction in order to get the borders off-screen, but thy're still there.

So, What series of Windows API commands should I be using exactly to get the window to open in a correctly maximised state,  and are there any 'subtleties' of alignment and/or spacings I should be aware of which may be causing this problem?
I guess the question boils down to 'what sequence of API commands does the window MAXIMISE button execute ?' but I can't find an answer anywhere.

Maybe there are also some subtleties I need to know about with regard to any windows dimensions parameters which could be creating the anomaly ?

Any help/guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)`

Comment: Use just `fortran` and optionally add some version to get more attention.

Comment: thanks for the advice about the Tags Vladimir F.

Comment: But you did not get it. Use the relevant tags. The [tag:winapi] tag is the most important! The Fortran version tags are there to distinguish versions, you should use just one of them.  Did you try the advice in the first comment?

Comment: I tried once to change the TAGs (removing WINAPI since you said that in your comment above !) but for some reason the edit I did doesn't appear to have registered.

Comment: Initially I used 'winapi' and 'fortran95' tags, then you said 'Use just fortran' Now you're saying the WINAPI is the most important !!!  (which I assumed it was) I'm confused.

Comment: just seen the note at bottom of post, did you edit the tags yesterday Vladimir ? re-introducing the WINAPI and deleting all the 3 additional fortran variants ? (didn't know other users could do that)